# How to use local notification with connect to host in background iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have an app, when reaching to alarm time, it will connect to host and get data show to notify dialog. 
I use HTTP POST to connect to host. My HTTP POST runs in a ViewController, so when connecting to host, it show that view.
Now, I want to do HTTP Post to host in background. It means, when reaching to alarm time, application will connect to host without that view, when get response from host successful, just show a view (dialog) with response data from host.
Can I do it in iPhone? If able, how do define NotificationName to call it in AppDelegate.m in this case? Class for HTTP Post modul same or different with View which will be showed if response from host success?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you should better use push notifications instead of local ones for what you need to do.

Comment: Because my server does not send notice message, so I can't use Push Notification. And notification is depends on user, they need it or not, so I must use Local Notification.

Comment: You can't alter the contents of a local notification after it's been scheduled, so you would have to get the data from the server during the setup of the notification and then schedule it. If the data on the server will change between the time you scheduled the notification and  the firing time and you would like to download that new data, I'm afraid that's not possible with local notifications.

Comment: Oh, I see. I think we can change its content. Thank you.